# putting values from database into select dropdown javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, ejs

I have a table in my database called `DIVISIONS`, and a column called `CATEGORIES`, where I store the users categories for their products. I want to basically take the results of the categories, and then put them into a select dropdown menu, where I can select which category I want...

Basically, when a user adds a product through my page to their website, they can select which category they want the product in. These categories are set by them, so they are stored in my table and called from my backend, passed to my front end, and now I want to put them into a select dropdown.

so my code basically runs an ejs loop to display all the categories, but they are retuned as a string, like so:

```
Car Cleaning Products Vacuum Parts Janitorial Supplies Power Washer Equipment Compressors and Accessories PPE Winter Products
```

this is fine if I can figure out how to split each value up basically, and put them in a select menu! please help!! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out! super silly mistake on my part:

basically I just did this:

```
 <select name="" id="">
    <% if(data.length){ 
      for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
       
          <option value="<%= data[i].CATEGORIES %>"><%= data[i].CATEGORIES %></option>
       
    <% }
  }else{ %>
  <% } %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

explode(" ",$str)

explode function can be used to put every word in an array
the repopulate the array in a string as follows

```
$mystring="<Select>";
foreach($x in $myarray)
{
$mystring.="<option>$x</option>";
}
$mystring.="</select>";
```